# Binding DataContext to object not always gives actual values, if I'm trying to take it from outside class

Tags: c#, wpf

I have UserControl in MainWindow with form constructed from GroupBox and TextBoxes. I binded DataContext of GroupBox and TextBox values to a specific object. When I'm using this object inside class, parameter values are always synchronized with TextBox values. My problem appears, when I'm trying to get synchronized values from outside. Object keeps old values.

Example of, what I'm trying to do:

```
class PersonForm : UserControl
{
  public Person person = new Person();
  public PersonForm()
  {
    person.name = "XXX";
    person.last_name = "XXXX";
    myGroupBox.DataContext = person;
  }

  private Person GetPersonFromForm() //this method will get synchronized object
  {
    return person; 
  }

  public Person GetPersonFromForm2() //if referenced from outside, old object will be returned
  {
    return person; 
  }
}

class Person()
{
  public string name { get; set;}
  public string last_name { get; set;}
}

//in other file

Person person = new Person();

private void GetPersonFromForm()
{
  person = MainWindow.personForm.person;
  person = MainWindow.personForm.GetPersonFromForm2();
  //both lines above will save to "person" old object
}
```

XAML:

```
<GroupBox Name="myGroupBox" Margin="10,10,0,10" Header="myGroupBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="580">
            <DockPanel>
                <StackPanel Width="260">
                    <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="Name"/>
                    <TextBox Margin="10,0" Name="name" Text="{Binding name}"/>
                    <Label Margin="5,0,0,0" Content="LastName"/>
                    <TextBox Margin="10,0" Name="last_name" Text="{Binding last_name}"/>
                </StackPanel>
                <StackPanel>
                    //more textboxes here
                </StackPanel>
            </DockPanel>
        </GroupBox>
```

I don't have an idea, why object behaves like this, but it's weird for me. Maybe it's my misunderstanding of, what DataContext is. Explain, please, if I'm doing it wrong.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any method in the UserControl that updates the `person` field. It's unclear how you expect that field to be changed "from outside". Just creating a new Person instance somewhere else won't magically have an effect on your UserControl.

Comment: I binded GroupBox to `person`. If I'm changing text in `TextBox` (inside GroupBox) binded to `name`, `person` object should have that changed value. I want it. When I'm calling `person` inside `UserControl`, it's okay. When I'm calling `person` from outside class, I'm getting object with old name.

Comment: Perhaps also show us the relevant parts of the UserControl's XAML.

Comment: @Clemens I edited post.

Comment: @Clemens I showed XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Since your `DataContext` is initialized in the constructor of your class, values of it won't be changed when you are changing `person` field itself. You might go for a Property `Person` with `Get` and `Set` and reset `DataContext` in the setter.

Comment: You didn't understand. I want to get Person class object with actual name and last_name values from binded TextBoxes. Inside class it's working, outside class it's not (I mean, I'm getting object not synchronized with binded TextBoxes).

Comment: I'm not sure that I get it correcetly but what if you try to pass those arguments in it's contstructor. And you gonna initialize it in PersonForm like this:

public Person person;
  public PersonForm()
  {
    person = new Person("XXX", "XXX");
    myGroupBox.DataContext = person;
  }

Comment: How is this related? I binded `person` to GroupBox by DataContext. GroupBox have binded TextBoxes. If I change value in `TextBox` binded to `name`, it should change in `person` too. When I'm calling `person` inside class, `name` has updated value from TextBox. When I'm calling `person` from outside, `name` has old value.